# How to preprocess this floating point data to use with scikit - Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I have dataset with 4000 features and 35 samples. All the features are floating point numbers between 1 and 3. eg: 2.68244527684596.

I'm struggling to get any classifier working on this data. I have used knn, svm (with linear,rbf,poly). Then I have learnt about normalization. Still, it's a bit complex for me and I cannot get this code working and giving me proper prediction.

The code I'm using to normalize data is:

```
train_data = preprocessing.scale(train_data)
train_data = preprocessing.normalize(train_data,'l1',0)
```

The code I'm trying to classify with is:

```
# SVM with poly
svc1 = svm.SVC(kernel='poly',degree=3)
svc1.fit(train_data[:-5], train_labels[:-5])
print "Poly SVM: ",svc1.predict(train_data[-5:])

# SVM with rbf
svc2 = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')
svc2.fit(train_data[:-5], train_labels[:-5])
print "RBF SVM: ",svc2.predict(train_data[-5:])

#SVM with linear
svc3 = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
svc3.fit(train_data[:-5], train_labels[:-5])
print "Linear SVM: ",svc3.predict(train_data[-5:])


# KNN
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(train_data[:-5], train_labels[:-5])
print "KNN :", knn.predict(train_data[-5:])

# Linear regression
logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
print('LogisticRegression score: %f' % logistic.fit(train_data[5:], train_labels[5:]).score(train_data[0:4], train_labels[0:4]))
```

I'm a newbie to machine learning and I'm working hard to learn more about all the concepts. I thought someone might point me in the right direction.

**Note:** I have only 35 samples and this is part of an assignment. I cannot get more data :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is not specific in any sense, then the standarization `preprocessing.scale` should be just fine. It forces each dimension to have 0-mean and standard deviation 1, so more or less it tries to enclose data in a 0-centered ball. It is worth noting that *you should not* use `normalize`, normalize forces each **sample** to have a unit norm, it has to be justified by your data (as you force your points to be placed **on the sphere** then). It is rarely the case.

There might be dozens of reasons why your classifiers do not work. In particular - is it your testing code? If so:

- you should not test just on 5 samples, learn about cross-validation (available in scikit-learn) and run at least 3-fold CV
- learn and test various hyperparameters. SVM requires at least for of them (depending on the kernel used, usually from 1 to 4 - for RBF kernel its C and gamma, for poly C, degree, coef0, ...); KNN around 3 (k, metric, weights); Logistic regression at least 1 (regularization)
- before building classifiers - look at your data. Plot it on a plane (PCA), try plotting projections on each feature - what are characteristics of your data? Is it balanced?
- **most importantly** - gather more data! You have 35 points in 4000 dimensional space... it is ridiculously small number of samples to do anything... if you are nto able to get at least 10x (preferably 100x) more points - start with reducing dimensionality of your data to at most 30 dimensions... use dimensionality reduction (even [scikit-learn PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)).

Comment: Thank you lejlot. This data is given by our professor for an assignment. He gave only 35 samples with 4000 features and test data is 15 more samples. I cannot get more data than that.  Thanks for pointing me to "cross validation" and "hyper parameters". I didn't use them till now. Once again thank you so much.

Comment: Then remember about dimensionality reduction too.

Comment: @lejlot "Simple PCA" won't work when you have fewer samples than features.

Comment: @bogatron Well you can still estimate covariance with regularization and proceed with PCA, in particular scikit-learn's pca will do so (from doc) `cov = components_.T * S**2 * components_ + sigma2 * eye(n_features)`; but obviously you are right that for this particular problem different techniques would be better.

Comment: @lejlot I agree you can do it with regularization but I wouldn't call that "simple PCA".